# How to run FindBugs off of Ivy downloaded JARs

Tags: java, ant, ivy, findbugs

I've got Ant and Ivy setup so that I can use Ivy downloaded JARs to run PMD.  Trying the same with FindBugs, setting the `findbugs.home` Ant property to `ivy-jars/findbugs`, where the Ivy JARs go.   I initially got the error that it couldn't find the JAR files under the `${findbugs.home}/lib` directory.  I fixed that by changing Ivy to download the JAR files into `ivy-jars/findbugs/lib`. However, this gave rise to the new error:

```
Executing findbugs FindBugsTask from ant task
Running FindBugs...
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassFormatException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be caused by three problems:

1. I retrieved the JAR files using `symlink="true"`. FindBugs dereferences the symlink to `findbugs.jar` and looks for all of its other JAR files under the same directory, but the way Ivy structures its cache only the `findbugs.jar` is in that directory.  This can be fixed easily enough by not using symlinks.
2. FindBugs wants its JAR files to sometimes have the filename format `[artifact].[ext]` and sometimes have the format `[artifact]-[revision].[ext]`, which can be solved by doing `<ivy:retrieve>` two times with different `pattern` values.
3. FindBugs wants the file name for the BCEL JAR file to be exactly `bcel-6.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` rather than `bcel-findbugs.jar` or `bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar`; this can be fixed with a symbolic link.

I consider this to just be a workaround, rather than a true solution, since #2 and #3 can't be how FindBugs is *intended* to be used under Ivy.  So if anyone knows the *right* way to do it, please provide a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the [documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html), the `home` attribute is *not* required.  Instead, you can provide a nested `classpath` element, which can be any [path-like structure](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path).

The following Ant target works for me:

```
<target name="findbugs" description="Run findbugs on the code">
    <ivy:retrieve/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="findbugs.classpath" conf="findbugs"/>
    <taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask" classpathref="findbugs.classpath"/>
    <findbugs>
        <classpath refid="findbugs.classpath"/>
        <class location="my-analysis-target.jar"/>
    </findbugs>
</target>
```

Where my `ivy.xml` is:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="meh" module="meh"/>
    <configurations defaultconfmapping="findbugs->default">
        <conf name="findbugs"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.google.code.findbugs" name="findbugs" rev="3.0.1" conf="findbugs"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```